# How to connect to mariaDB hosted in AWS from a docker container?

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-rds

I have setup a `mariadb` instance in `AWS RDS`. The DB is in a private VPC with no internet access. I can setup an EC2 VM and connect to the DB from `DBeaver` using SSH tunneling.

I have an application running in a docker container and want to setup a connection to the mariadb instance. How do I setup the connection so the container can piggyback on an SSH tunnel and connect to mariadb?